# jqplot click events not firing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jqplot

I am unable to get catch the most basic jqplot click events in my rails 3.1 app.  I want to catch any click on my graph.  I have created a simple test page that still doesn't work:

```
    <head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery"%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.jqplot.min.js"%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.jqplot.min.css" %>
</head>
<body>
<p>Chart test</p>
<div id='chart1'></div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);

  function myClickHandler(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    alert('you have triggered click action');
  }
  $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', myClickHandler]);

});
</script>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the graph.  I have tried many different approaches.

I'm using version 3.1.0 of the jquery-rails gem (version 1.11 of jquery) and version 1.0.8r1250 of jqplot.

I'm at the point where I don't even know what else to do to troubleshoot.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set up the eventListenerHooks before creating the plot:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


  function myClickHandler(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    alert('you have triggered click action');
  }
  $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', myClickHandler]);

  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]); //moved


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use the builtin jQuery event handler? It doesn't require creating an eventListenerHook...

```
$.jqplot('chart1',...);
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotClick', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    //handle jqplotClick
});
```